# Using MomentJS for Default Date in MongoDB Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, momentjs

I'm trying to use MomentJS to get non-localized UTC time and set that as the default for new documents created in Mongo.

```
var SubFavoriteSchema = new Schema({
    user : { type: String, ref: 'Account'},
    date : {type: Date, default: moment.utc()}
});
```

The problem is, moment.utc() returns the date that the Node server started. Thus if I start the server on Jan 1, all the documents get a UTC time of Jan 1, even if the document is created on Jan 10.

Any idea why it keeps getting the server's start time instead of the current time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling the `moment.utc()` function (once) when creating the schema, so the same resulting value is used when creating new documents.

However, you don't need to use `moment` for this, `default: Date.now` will do what you want as that function returns the current UTC time. Note that you don't *call* the `now` function, you just pass the function itself. That's the key difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a factory function for that.

```
var currDate(){
  return function(){
    return moment.utc();
  }
}

var SubFavoriteSchema = new Schema({
    user : { type: String, ref: 'Account'},
    date : {type: Date, default: currDate()}
});
```